# jquery - having the selector change all appropriate attributes and not just the first one found

Tags: javascript, jquery

I had a basic question on the jquery selector.

```
$(function () {
    $('.grid').hover(function(){
    var divId = $(this).attr("divId");
    var $this = $('#' + divId);
    var newSource = $this.data('alt-src');
    $this.data('alt-src', $this.attr('src'));
    $this.attr('src', newSource);
    });
});
```

If I were to hover on a div with the class="grid", how can have all the divs as found by var $this = $('#' + divId); change their imgs? Meaning, when this function executes, only the first div with the appropriate id has it's img src change. I would like it so that all the divs with that appropriate id (attribute) change rather than the first one change.

Also, I would appreciate any help with where I could modify this so that when the img changes it's fades in 'slow'.

Thanks.

Comment: you should not use multiple elements with same id, try using class

Comment: jQuery knows that IDs must be unique, so an ID selector will never match more than one element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The specific difference between an ID and a Class attribute is that IDs are expected to always be unique, whereas classes are intended to be used to identify a group of elements which share a common grouping. If you have multiple elements with the same ID, you are using HTML incorrectly. By rewriting your code such that each element has a unique ID, you can count on those IDs identifying the specific element they're associated with and then give groups of elements which you want to select together a specific class, which is the appropriate way to select a group of elements like you're trying to.

Comment: Thank you for explaining it fully. So if I change it around to group it by class, I run into a jquery problem where the first image src ends up showing up in the other divs. I'm not really sure what I'm doing wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated. http://jsfiddle.net/LmVRZ/214/

Comment: Here's a working version of your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LmVRZ/222/ 
Your issue is that you were trying to access the attributes directly of your $this element, but that element refers to the entire group of elements, so you were only actually getting one value for all of them. by using .each(), you can run a function on each item in the selected group. Let me know if you have any other questions about it!

Comment: Thank you. I had tried something like var $this= $('.' + divId).each(function(){ but could not get it to work. Thanks again. One last question if you don't mind. Are you able to include a timing function like with fadeIn and fadeOut when dealing with the hover handlerIn and Out event function?